# Is it possible for a variable transformer to work with non-literal tokens?

Tags: macros, scheme, racket

`make-variable-transformer` (or `make-set!-transformer`, as it is called in Racket) can work with identifiers hardcoded in the literal list of the macro definition. The following example with `set!` invariably comes up when variable transformers are mentioned:

```
(make-variable-transformer
  (λ (stx)
    (syntax-case stx (set!)
      ((set! id _) ...)
      (id ...))))
```

This is nice and all, useful for transparently integrating foreign structures with primitive operations known ahead of time, and it's a bonus that it can work through identifier syntax and rename transformers.

But what I'm wondering is if it's possible to work with syntax dynamically like:

```
(let-syntax ((@ (make-variable-transformer
                  (λ (stx)
                    (syntax-case stx ()
                     ((v @ i) (vector? #'v) #'(vector-ref v i)))))))
  (#(0 1 2) @ 1))
=> 1
```

This doesn't work because the macro call doesn't match the template as `syntax-case` expects `@` to be in the initial position since there's no `v` in the literal list (and it probably assigns `@` to `v` pattern variable).

In short: Is it possible to write a syntax transformer that can accomplish this without reader extensions or overriding application, perhaps through a metamacro that rewrites the literal token list of an inner `syntax-case` (à la Petrofsky extraction)?

NB: The vector example itself is unimportant and I'm not interested in alternative solutions to this exact use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since there's no v in the literal list (and it probably assigns @ to v pattern variable).

Not really. `set!` is a [special case](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-model.html#%28part._transformer-model%29) that the macro expander handles specifically to make it cooperate with `make-variable-transformer`. But for other literals, they will fail. E.g.,

```
(let-syntax ((@ (make-variable-transformer
                 (λ (stx)
                   (syntax-case stx (v)
                     ((v @ i) #'1))))))
  (v @ 1))
```

fails with `v: unbound identifier`.

The second issue with your above code is the side condition `(vector? #'v)`. `#'v` is a syntax object, so `(vector? #'v)` will always result in `#f`. It's unclear what is the right behavior. For example, do you intend for:

```
(define v (vector 1 2 3))
(v @ 1)
```

to work? If so, a compile-time side condition would be inappropriate, because it's not known if `v` is a vector at compile-time.

---

For your main question, the answer is no. It's not possible under the constraints that you imposed. The [expansion steps](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-model.html#%28part._expand-steps%29) are detailed here, and none of the steps looks beyond the head of the list.

But if we don't care about the constraints. I.e., overriding `#%app` is OK. It could work.

An issue that you need to think about is, suppose you have `(a b c)` where `b` is your kind of macro and `a` is a regular macro. Who should get the control first? If `a` should get the control first, you can override `#%app` to implement this kind of macro. Here's my quick implementation.

```
#lang racket

(require syntax/parse/define
         (only-in racket [#%app racket:#%app])
         (for-syntax syntax/apply-transformer))

(begin-for-syntax
  (struct my-transformer (t)))

(define-syntax-parser #%app
  [(_ x ...)
   (define transformer
     (for/first ([operand (attribute x)]
                 #:when (and (identifier? operand)
                             (my-transformer?
                              (syntax-local-value operand (λ () #f)))))
       
       (syntax-local-value operand)))
   (cond
     [transformer (local-apply-transformer
                   (my-transformer-t transformer)
                   #'(x ...)
                   'expression)]
     [else #'(racket:#%app x ...)])])

(define-syntax @
  (my-transformer
   (syntax-parser
     [(v _ i) #'(vector-ref v i)])))

(define v (vector 42 1337 1729))
(v @ 1) ;=> 1337
```

Finally, you can always override `#%module-begin` and simulate the macro expander. It's an overkill solution, but could be appropriate if you want more advanced features, like allowing users to customize precedence so that `b` is expanded before `a`.

Comment: "`set!` is a special case that the macro expander handles specifically. But for other literals, they will fail."

So this is the core detail I was missing all along. Racket's name for the procedure makes more sense now. I knew it was possible by overriding application or with reader extensions but wanted to see if it's possible through variable transformers. Thanks for the in-depth explanation.